Can't find module @prisma/client
When I use Prisma Client I have a problem. After the import i have a mistake: no module found "@prisma/client"   enter image description hereenter image description here
I tried to install node_modules again and it didn't helped. It's just can't find this module in app folder and I have no idea what to do.

Sharing my issue here as it is very specific: In my case it was due to the baseUrl property I had set for the project: "./" . However I am working on a monorepo and all other config is extended from a base ts file.
I just had to remove the baseUrl property and the prisma client was resolved properly. According to the docs you might not need it either:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#baseUrl
